# Filter Result Array from Loop in Power-Automate

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I loop thru a lot of data in an array to filter it. I the example I only have one Supplier_ID to filter, in real life it would be a lot of.

As result I like to have one big array with all needed Supplier_IDs. This works fine.

But:
How can I avoid the `"body":`  'part / item' in the output of my COMPOSE (in German 'Verfassen') step?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use expression

```
outputs('Filter_relevante_SupplierItems')?['body']
```

instead of

```
outputs('Filter_relevante_SupplierItems')
```

in the `Verfassen` step.

=============================**Update**============================

Have a try with expression: `outputs('Filter_relevante_SupplierItems')[0]?['body']`

=============================**Update 2**============================

Summarize from the chat room for other communities reference:

OP uses `union()` method to union two arrays in loop to solve the problem.

Another solution for others reference: we can also use `replace()` method to replace `{"body":[` with empty string, `replace(outputs(...), '{"body":[', '')`. And then replace `]}` with empty string, `replace(outputs(...), ']}', '')`. It can also remove the `body`.

Comment: @Hury_Shen : If I use this I get the following error Massage:
Template language expressions in the input of the "Verfassen" action in line "1" and column "28810" cannot be processed: The template language expression "outputs('Filter_relevante_SupplierItems')? ['body']" cannot be evaluated because the body property cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected with an integer index. For more information about how to use it, see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, please have a try with the "update" in my answer.

Comment: @Hury_Shen: This works fine if I have only one Item in the ```LOOP``` ("Auf alle anwenden relevante Supplier") Step. If there are more than one, I only get the first part/loop.....

Comment: @Chris Could you please provide a sample of the format you want to get at last ? I will help you format it.

Comment: @Chris Do you want the format like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OusN9.png) ?

Comment: @Hury_Shen: 
[
  {
    "SupplierItem_ID": "54446492",
    "Product_ID": 5111569000,
    "Supplier_SKU": "253003",
    "Supplier_ID": 10000310
  },
  {
    "SupplierItem_ID": "15672144",
    "Product_ID": 146993000,
    "Supplier_SKU": "426816",
    "Supplier_ID": 10000310
  }]   ..... I need one Array for all the data

Comment: @Chris Could you please also provide a sample of your original data format ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228612/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-chris).

Answer (score 1):

Now I solved the union of the arrays inside the loop.
[image]